# EF 5 Code First Dictionary Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Is there any way to map a dictionary using Entity Framework 5?

From what I found while searching, it has not been supported until EF 4.1, not sure if EF 5 provides any innovative methods to map it easily.

I am using the dictionary to store a "variable number of properties"  for each object of a class.

If it's not supported what would be the best alternative data structure to use in this scenario (supported by EF)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No dictionary is still not supported. You must use traditional one-to-many relation. Where each your current key/value pair in dictionary will be stored as record in table and related with foreign key to principal entity (that one which contained the dictionary). The entity should look like:

```
public class Item {
    public int Id { get; set; } // unique autogenerated database key
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public int PrincipalId { get; set; } // FK to principal entity
}
```

Types of properties and name of foreign key will differ for your current situation. The principal entity will just have:

```
public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

Comment: If I do store my data  this way, is it possible to still access it the way I access data in a dictionary? I mean is there a way I can "feed the data" to an unmapped dictionary object and access it (so that the lookup is efficient as in a dictionary)?

Comment: No unless you create the dictionary yourselves after loading the entity - you will have both association defined by the collection and your dictionary. You will also need to synchronize changes made to dictionary with the collection to persist them.